# How to create menu & sub Menu in smart device app in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6.5, smart-device

I am new to the smart device application in visual studio 2008. I have to create a smart device app which will have menu & sub menu at the top (similar to desktop application). Once user clicks on the sub menu it will navigate to a form.

Please let me know where I will find resource/study material to learn more about building smart device application using visual studio 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Windows mobile only supports one menu line (your main menu) due to the limitted space on the screen. But you may switch between different main menus from code.

Good books for CF programming starters are Paul Yao's Programming The Compact Framework and for mor background: Douglas Boling's Programming Windows CE .Net. And do not forget about the basic and read Charles Petzold's Windows Programming book.

Always keep in mind that a Windows Mobile device has less resources and smaller screen than desktop windows. The API is a subset of the full framework, same for the natice C/C++ API.